# class and header for C++

Tags: c++, function, class, header-files

I am trying to learn how to use class functions in c++.. I have code that I written here but something is wrong.. I know you don't do the homework..but if you can help me out to learn it with out using things like did you look here..I have done research ..google cpluplus site..but there is something i am not getting so hopefully you can help me out. I am using Dev-C++.

The code take two numbers and then calculates them based on choice of useing..add..subtract..multiply..and devide

this is my first error code

```
30  23  C:\Users\ddempsey\Desktop\class\addSubtractMain.cpp [Error] no matching function for call to 'addSubtract::initialize()'
```

here is my header code

```
#ifndef CLASS_addSubtract_h
#define CLASS_addSubtract_h

class addSubtract
{
    private:
       int one;
       int two;


    public:
        int add ();
        int sub ();
        int multi ();
        int devide ();
        void initialize (int n1, int n2);
};
```

class

```
using namespace std;

#include "addSubtract.h"



void addSubtract::initialize(int n1, int n2)
{
    one = n1;
    two = n2;
}
int addSubtract::add()
{

   return(one + two);
}
int addSubtract::sub()
{

   return(one - two);
}

int addSubtract::multi()
{

   return(one * two);
}

int addSubtract::devide()
{

   return(one / two);
}
//class function code
```

main

```
#include "addSubtract.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    addSubtract numbers; //instantiate an object
    int n1;
    int n2;
    char choice;

    cout<<"Enter first number to calculate  ";
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Enter second number to calculate  ";
    cin>>n2;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"what would you like to do\n ";
    cout<<" add enter      (+)\n ";
    cout<<" subtract enter (-)\n ";
    cout<<" multiply enter (*)\n ";
    cout<<" devide enter   (/)\n ";
    cin>>choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case '+' :
            numbers.initialize(int1, int2); 
            cout<<n1<<" + "<<n2<<" ="<<numbers.add()<<endl;
            break;
            case '-' :
            numbers.initialize(int1, int2); 
            cout<<n1<<" - "<<n2<<" = "<<numbers.sub()<<endl;
            break;
            case '*' :
            numbers.initialize(int1, int2); 
            cout<<n1<<" * "<<n2<<" = "<<numbers.multi()<<endl;
            break;
            case '/' :
            numbers.initialize(int1, int2); 
            cout<<n1<<" / "<<n2<<" = "<<numbers.devide()<<endl;
            break;  
            default:
            cout<<"invalid choice" <<endl;          
        }


system("PAUSE");    
return 0;

}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `n1` and `n2` by `int1` and `int2`, don't you?

Comment: you are missing 
    #endif

Answer (score 2):

`numbers.initialize(int1, int2);` to `numbers.initialize(n1, n2);`

Except for this your code is fine.

Comment: Im now getting these errors.                                       32 C:\Users\ddempsey\Desktop\class\addSubtractMain.cpp undefined reference to `addSubtract::initialize(int, int)'                                                                 33 C:\Users\ddempsey\Desktop\class\addSubtractMain.cpp undefined reference to `addSubtract::add()'

Comment: Your linker is unable to pickup source file of addSubtract. Did you keep the definitions in a separate cpp file ?

Comment: Generally not. Most linkers will search the directory of header files for any source files. If you keep your addSubtract.cpp in the same header file as your addSubtract.h, it should be fine.

Comment: Check this - http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f128/what-causes-linker-error-in-dev-c-634223.html

Comment: Yes, they are in the same file

Comment: Did you removed any header files your IDE created ? Try starting a new project and not removing any headers ur IDE creates

Comment: I know in class the instructor made us go to tools...Compiler..and in the ("add the following commands when calling the linker") box .he had us add something from our code..I belive it was one of the #includes.. i tried doing that with several of the #includes but it didnt work..

Comment: I figured it out guys. The class function portion of my program...    ie..(addSubtract.cpp) was not supplied to my compiler..so I went into tools--compiler and added ("addSubtract.cpp") to the (Add the folloiwng commands when calling the linker) box... all is well code runs fine..